# Restrict access to GCP cloud source repository by the client machine IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

in GCP, we are using Cloud source repository. Is there a way you can restrict access right by client IP address in addition to IAM? workarounds are fine.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce in my own project and it seems that the only way to restrict a repository created on Cloud Source Repositories is by IAM, assigning the proper roles, not by IP.

You can check the following [information](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/granting-users-access) for Granting user access to repositories and projects, It describes how you can provide users access to repositories and projects, and what actions those users can take.

Examples of user actions include the following:

- Listing repositories
- Creating new repositories
- Updating repositories

Unfortunately this option doesn't include IP Address restrictions.

On the other hand, I recommend you to review the following guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to provide a better context on what you are doing and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Support for additional access restrictions to Cloud Source Repositories would be very welcome. VPC Service Controls coverage is very comprehensive now - https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/supported-products. Appreciating that Cloud Source Repositories differs from purely API based services, it would still be good to see some intent in this direction.